# Regulator magic smoke

Tags: attiny

I have accidentally released the magic smoke from the regulator on a digispark board. I did this when I accidentally plugged a circuit into the 5V and the VIn instead of the 5V and Gnd, and then plugged the board into the USB port.

The attiny chip still works - I know because I plugged it in to the USB ,with no circuitry attached, and the uploaded program still runs happily.

My question is, is there any possibility that when the magic smoke was released from the regulator, the attiny was also damaged?

Secondly, is there any harm in leaving the dead regulator on the board? Or am I better off cutting it off?

Comment: Better replace the regulator on the board. Cutting or leaving is not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear voltage regulators have an internal parasitic diode that shorts the output to the input. You have burned out this diode which has destroyed the regulator, but it is highly unlikely that any other components have been damaged. You can get away with cutting away the legs of the regulator, but complete removal will be difficult due to the large size of the tab connection and will likely result in damage to the other components.